# SQL relational insert to 2 tables in single query without resorting to mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I'm not totally new to SQL, but am rusty and struggle with MYSQL (using PhPMyAdmin)... looked at this: [MySQL insert to multiple tables (relational)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225024/mysql-insert-to-multiple-tables-relational)
and some other related topics, but haven't found an answer. I'm simplifying my example to get the point across.

If you have two tables:

```
'table1' has: id (primary key, auto-increment), description (text)
'table2' has: id (primary key, auto-increment), title (text), description_id (int)
```

How do I create a singe INSERT statement so that `description_id` is storing the value for `table1.id` ?

I know there are php ways to do 2 queries but I'd like to do it all in  SQL, there must be a way? Should I set up my tables differently? [I read something about foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324780/mysql-foreign-key-relations-vs-mysql-insert-id-to-relate-tables) and have no idea if that's applicable.

Thanks!

Comment: INSERT statements can only affect one table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: I'm coming across something promising on the mysql docs: `INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');         # generate ID by inserting NULL
INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');  # use ID in second table`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks to @hackattack, who found this ? [answered already elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization).

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
  VALUES('test', 'test')
INSERT INTO profiles (userid, bio, homepage) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Hello world!', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
COMMIT;
```

**BUT, ALAS - that didn't work.**
The MySQL 5 reference shows it slightly different syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`description`) 
  VALUES('sdfsdf');# 1 row affected.
INSERT INTO `table1`(`table1_id`,`title`) 
  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'hello world');
```

And, lo/behold - that works!

**More trouble ahead**
Although the query will succeed in phpMyAdmin, my PHP installation complains about the query and throws a syntax error. I resorted to doing this the php-way and making 2 separate queries and using `mysql_insert_id()`

I find that annoying, but I guess that's not much less server load than a transaction.

Comment: Exactly what [I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568744/215042) (Thanks for voting up or accepting answer...). Strictly speaking though, this is still 2 queries. It's just that they're being executed as one single, atomic, action.

Comment: @roblll aha, I learned something new from your comment - an atomic action... well at the end of the day its about efficiency and server load etc... so whatever makes it tighter and faster, that's what I was after.

Comment: @RobIII and How is that different from my suggested alternative in PHP?

Comment: @tim Transactions might actually slow things down and you have to take into account the 'penalties' you're paying for them. Having said that; I'd use them.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568744/215042) was/is: **You can't**. Then I suggested using a transaction to make it at least (on the application level) seem to be an atomic action. You could still supply all the values and do "one" insert. Your answer assumes data already in one or more tables. Actually, I don't see in what way my answer ("you can't") resembles [yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11568801/215042)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert in more than one table (writeable views aside*, but AFAIK MySQL doesn't support them) with an insert statement.

What *might* be of interest for you are [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) which allow you to 'group' statements into one single "[atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29)" action.

<sup><sub>* Which, in fact, only would allow updates, not inserts (I believe, but now I'm starting to doubt it... anyways, it's not the issue here anyway)</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use Triggers here so that whenever table2 gets an insert operation, a trigger executes to do an insert on table1.

Comment: And how would you supply the values for the fields of the second table to this trigger?